# How to get last column number of a dynamic excelsheet?

Tags: java

I want to get the last column number of a row when my excel sheet contains data having a dynamic number of columns.
for e.g. row 1 contains data in 2 columns, row 2 contains data in 10 columns, row 3 contains data in 5 columns.

```
FileInputStream fis;
    fis = new FileInputStream(Excel_FilePath);
    XSSFWorkbook workbk=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    //readExcel.setExcelFile(Property.getProperty("TestData_SheetName"));
    XSSFSheet actionsheet=workbk.getSheet(Property.getProperty("TestData_SheetName"));
    readExcel.setExcelFile(Property.getProperty("TestData_SheetName"));
    System.out.println("The current excel sheet name is : "+Property.getProperty("TestData_SheetName"));
    System.out.println("The Test case ID inside the getColumnCount method is : "+DriverExecution.MainTestScenarioID);
    CellRangeAddress rowscount = readExcel.mergedrowscount(DriverExecution.MainTestScenarioID);

    int Frow=rowscount.getFirstRow();
    int Lrow=rowscount.getLastRow();

    System.out.println("The First Row number is : "+Frow);
    System.out.println("The Last Row number is : "+Lrow);
    //colcnt = actionsheet.getRow(Lrow).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    colcnt = actionsheet.getRow(Lrow).getLastCellNum();
    System.out.println("Number of columns is : "+colcnt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(Excel_FilePath));
Workbook excelWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
Sheet datatypeSheet = excelWorkbook.getSheetAt(0); //This will get you first sheet     from workbook
Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
Row firstRow = iterator.next();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
    int currentRowNumberOfColumns = currentRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
}
```

Comment: Using `int currentRowNumberOfColumns = currentRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();` I am always getting the number of columns for the headers only.

Comment: Suppose, my excel sheet contains 12 headers and then below it on first column it's a merged rows, and then data in the rest of the columns. But some rows conatins data in 2 columns, whereas for other rows it contains data into, let's say 4 columns then in some other rows it contains data into 8 columns. And so when I am trying to get the number of columns containing data for any particular row, it is always giving the number as, the number of columns containing data in the header.

Comment: **Test Case ID || Object Name || Test Data1 || Test Data2 || Test Data3 || Test Data4 || Test Data5 || Test Data6 || Test Data7 || Test Data8 || Test Data9 || Test Data10 || Test Data11 || Test Data12 ||**   <br/>  TC1 || Object1 || Data1 || Data2 
  <br/>  TC1 || Object 2 || Data1 || Data2 || Data3 || Data4